# Realm Swift - How to remove an item at a specific index position?

Tags: swift, realm

I am storing a simple list of id's as GUIDs in Realm, but would like the ability to delete an object at a particular index position.

So for example, I want to remove 04b8d81b9e614f1ebb6de41cb0e64432 at index position 1, how can this be achieved? Do I need to add a primary key, or is there a way to remove the item directly using the given index position?

```
Results<RecipeIds> <0x7fa844451800> (
    [0] RecipeIds {
        id = a1e28a5eef144922880945b5fcca6399;
    },
    [1] RecipeIds {
        id = 04b8d81b9e614f1ebb6de41cb0e64432;
    },
    [2] RecipeIds {
        id = cd0eead0dcc6403493c4f110667c34ad;
    }
)
```

It seems like this should be a straightforward ask, but I can't find any documentation on it. Even a pointer in the right direction would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Results` are auto-updating and you cannot directly modify them. You need to update/add/delete objects in your `Realm` to effect the state of your `Results` instance.

So you can simply grab the element you need from your `Results` instance, delete it from `Realm` and it will be removed from the `Results` as well.

Assuming the `Results` instance shown in your question is stored in a variable called `recipes`, you can do something like the following:

```
let recipeToDelete = recipes.filter("id == %@","04b8d81b9e614f1ebb6de41cb0e64432")
try! realm.write {
    realm.delete(recipeToDelete)
}
```